# Vim find/replace highlighting

Tags: search, replace

I'm a long time Vim user but a few months back started dabbling in Emacs.  One of the things I really liked about Emacs was when doing a find/replace `s/you/me` it would highlight the word I was changing in red and then the word I was replacing it with in green:

[image]

Is there a plugin that can do this in Vim? I've tried searching but I either don't know how to explain what I'm looking for or I can't find it because in searching I just come across a ton of tutorials on *how* to search and not how to implement this functionality.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: incsearch can show the search in the substitute, i think, but idk of any plugin that shows the replacement

Comment: It's been a while since I've used emacs, and when I did I didn't know what I was doing, but I don't think this is its default behaviour. If you're able to figure out what plugin/setting is enabling this feature in _Emacs_, then you might have more luck searching for a Vim replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options to replicate this functionality in vim:

1. vim8 supports this out of the box with incsearch
2. inccommand in neovim
3. if you’re not using neovim or are stuck on an older version of vim, you can use the plugin vim-over: https://github.com/osyo-manga/vim-over